# Javascript: return nested function(asynchronus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, nested

I want to access(or print) d from return of function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm just by calling get.Location .I guess I may use callbacks but it dosent't work(and/or I'm a n00b).Is it possible to do this in this case? For example :`document.write(getLocation(45.123,12.123)) //would print d somehow .`

Thank you in advance.

```
getLocation(45.123,12.123);

function getLocation(a,b) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){ajmo(p,a,b);});
  }
}

function ajmo(position,a,b) {
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  lng = position.coords.longitude;
  getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(a,b,lat, lng);
}


function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat_origin, lon_origin, lat_pos, lon_pos) {
  var R = 6371;
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat_pos - lat_origin);
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon_pos - lon_origin);
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_origin)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_pos)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Comment: You don't return values from asynchronous code as you're working in [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), you need callbacks, or promises.

Comment: Yup, `return` is crucial here and it's missing in first two functions.

Comment: @elclanrs any idea how to implement it?(callbacks).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: access return of the nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504667/javascript-access-return-of-the-nested-function) -- please don't ask questions twice (or [thrice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23504185/218196)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an HTML element with id = "distance", you probably need this:

```
function getLocation(a, b, element) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lng = position.coords.longitude;
      var d = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(a,b,lat, lng);
      document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = d;
    });
  }
}


function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat_origin, lon_origin, lat_pos, lon_pos) {
  var R = 6371;
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat_pos - lat_origin);
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon_pos - lon_origin);
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_origin)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat_pos)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}  


getLocation(45.123, 12.123, 'distance');
```

Comment: Since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, `getLocation` function cannot return any outcome from the asynchronous operation.

Comment: So,it is impossible to write 'd' with document.write(getLocation(a,b));?

Comment: If you want to set 'd' to the outcome value, then you should declare it outside `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm` function. But, since `d` will be assigned asynchronously, it's better to think what you want to *do* with this value, rather than just get the value.
If you want to print it, then above code is enough. If you want to access it, call the function you want after it is assigned.

Comment: I just want to print it(d) in html only by calling getLocation.

Comment: You are actually do that :) Just replace `console.log` with code for setting HTML to an element.
If you want, you can even pass the element id or class to `getLocation` and set the HTML of a specific element. When working with asynchronous programming, you have to swift your mind from the notion of having a function return a value.

Comment: Can You please edit your answer because I really can't make it work :)) Thank you!

Comment: Would give you +99999 if i could.Thanks.